# GitHub API CORS Policy

Tags: javascript, cors, github-api

I'm using jQuery and ajax to do a get request to the GitHub API but after I refresh about 3 times, the request starts to fail saying:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.github.com/users/X/repos' from origin 'my domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

even though, I've registered my domain as a GitHub OAuth app.

Here are is my javascript:

```js
let repos = [];
const isEnglish = document.documentElement.lang == 'en';
class Repo {
  constructor(name, description, webUrl, apiUrl) {
    this._name = name;
    this._description = description;
    this._webUrl = webUrl;
    this._apiUrl = apiUrl;
    this._languages = [];
    this.fetchLanguages();
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  get description() {
    return this._description;
  }

  get url() {
    return this._webUrl;
  }

  get languages() {
    return this._languages;
  }

  set languages(value) {
    this._languages = value;
  }

  async fetchLanguages() {
    const url = this._apiUrl + '/languages';
    await $.ajax({
      url: url,
      complete: data => {
        this._languages = Object.keys(data.responseJSON);
      },
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(async () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/X/repos',
    complete: xhr => {
      repos = xhr.responseJSON.map(json => {
        return new Repo(json.name, json.description, json.html_url, json.url);
      });
      // build up list based on data
      const container = document.getElementById('projectListContainer');
      repos.forEach(repo => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');

        //header
        const collapsibleHeader = document.createElement('div');
        collapsibleHeader.classList.add('collapsible-header');
        const headerText = document.createTextNode(repo.name);
        collapsibleHeader.appendChild(headerText);
        li.appendChild(collapsibleHeader);

        //body
        const collapsibleBody = document.createElement('div');
        collapsibleBody.classList.add('collapsible-body');

        const description = document.createElement('p');
        const descText = document.createTextNode(repo.description);
        description.appendChild(descText);
        collapsibleBody.appendChild(description);

        const languages = document.createElement('p');
        languages.style.marginTop = '1rem';
        const langTxt = isEnglish ? 'Languages used: ' : 'Talen gebruikt: ';
        const langText = document.createTextNode(langTxt + repo.languages);
        languages.appendChild(langText);
        collapsibleBody.appendChild(languages);

        const url = document.createElement('a');
        url.href = repo.url;
        url.target = '_blank';
        url.style.marginTop = '1rem';
        url.style.display = 'block';
        url.style.fontSize = '12px';
        const urlText = document.createTextNode(repo.url);
        url.appendChild(urlText);
        collapsibleBody.appendChild(url);

        li.appendChild(collapsibleBody);
        container.appendChild(li);
      });
    },
    error: () => {
      const container = document.getElementById('projectListContainer');
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('center');
      const txt = isEnglish
        ? 'Something went wrong or the request limit is reached, check back later!'
        : 'Er is iets fout gegeaan of het maximum aantal requests is bereikt, kom later terug!';
      const text = document.createTextNode(txt);
      div.appendChild(text);
      container.appendChild(div);
    },
  });
  updateTable();
});

const updateTable = () => {
  repos.forEach(repo => {
    const tdLanguages = document.getElementsByClassName(`${repo.name}Lang`)[0];
    tdLanguages.innerHTML = repo.languages.join(', ');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unauthenticated requests, they limit up to 60 requests an hour. You can increase this upto 5000 per hours by authenticating the api requests.

So when I was facing this problem a couple of weeks ago, I created `personal_auth_token` at gihub and passed this token in the `headers` and the problem was solved.

To generate `personal_auth_token`, login to `github.com`, *go to settings -> developers settings -> Personal access tokens* and generate one.

Pass this token in `headers` under `Auhtorization: *token*`. So in your AJAX request, it could look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: *yourUrl*
    ...
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', *token*));
    },
});
```

One thing to note here is **DON'T** push the code with this `token` on github if the repository is public. That gets immediately detected and the `token` is revoked and you're be required to create again one.

> For API requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up
>   to 5000 requests per hour. Authenticated requests are associated with
>   the authenticated user, regardless of whether Basic Authentication or
>   an OAuth token was used. This means that all OAuth applications
>   authorized by a user share the same quota of 5000 requests per hour
>   when they authenticate with different tokens owned by the same user.
>
> For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows for up to 60
>   requests per hour. Unauthenticated requests are associated with the
>   originating IP address, and not the user making requests.

https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting

Another solution that effectively worked in my case was solving the `CORS` issue with a proxy server. In this, you're just required to append the API request URL to a proxy service provider such as, `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

```
var url = "http://example.com/repo"; //your api request url,
var proxyUrl = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${url}`;

fetch(proxyUrl)... //Make a request with this proxy url to navigate CORS issue
```

Comment: Very helpful response, thank you for that but I just have one more question. Since I'm using static HTML en JS, I'm not sure if this is possible but is there something like a .env file which I can use to store that token and import it when I need it?

Comment: In my case, since that was a React application, I was storing the token in `.env` file. In your case you may do something like `export const environment = {
  dev: true,
  token: *token*,
};` and import this in your `.js` file

Comment: but how can I then allow this file to be used without the `cannot use import statement outside a module` error? I've already made my script tag of `type="module"`

Comment: You may do something like `<script type="module" src="path of your dile"></script>` if you're not using a bundling tool like `webpack` in your application. Or just declare a `constant` object in the same file and use that. For. eg. `var myConstants = {env: 'dev', 'token': *myToken*}`

Comment: You should NOT embed a personal access token in a webpage. Anybody accessing your website could access this token and github personal access token have large scope and never expire so they can be abused easily. You mentioned GitHub OAuth in your question, it's a good way to go

Comment: Yup indeed. In fact, If you push code on github with the token, it detects automatically and revoke the token. But yes, you have to be more careful if you’re sharing the code on other sources and ensure that the token is not shared along with others. However, this token is meant to be for the private access and can be used during the development by an individual developer.

Answer (score 1):

To tell the truth, GitHub REST API doesn't reject CORS (see [old document](https://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing)).
Even if you have the CORS error, it must be another problem.

In my case, it was because of

- old information: **the header requires NOT `Authorization: bearer YOUR__TOKEN` but `Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN`**
- bad usage: only mistype
- CORS error but success: the console returns the CORS error, but the connection has succeeded.